# ios: Html parsing iframe tag issue

Tags: html, ios, objective-c

I am using the default html parser to parse the html text:

```
NSData *data = [receivedText dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
     NSMutableAttributedString *text = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithData:data
                                                                                  options:@{
                                                                                            NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType,
                                                                                            NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: @(NSUTF8StringEncoding)}
                                                                       documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
```

But when the received html text contains a iframe tag, my app crashes. It gives a bad access code issue.

My html text is

```
<p dir="ltr">iFrame tag test<iframe src='http://www.test.com/'></iframe></p>
```

Is there something wrong in the code? App works fine when I replace `NSHTMLTextDocumentType` with any other type, but I need to use this type only.
I am using UITextView to display it.

Comment: It worked, `text` is correctly transformed. If your app crash, what the console says? It crashes when you display it in the `UITextView`?

Comment: When I tried to parse, it gave a crash saying bad access code

Answer (score 0):

Use UIWebView. iframe tags may not work with UITextView